# failed to start scanner: invalid argument (xsane)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, scanner, xsane

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 9.10 and now my Brother MFC 210C won't scan (printing is fine).

I installed the following packages according to the instructions on the Brother site:

```
cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb
mfc210clpr-1.0.2-1.i386.deb
brscan2-0.2.4-0.i386.deb
```

When I start xsane and click "Scan", I get the error:

```
failed to start scanner: invalid argument
```

This scanner was working fine on 9.04 (and previous versions).

**EDIT:** I also did:

```
sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb
sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/*
```

Didn't help!

Comment: For me, other scanning programs besides xsane were working, even acquiring a preview in xsane was working, but this error would pop up at the end of trying to scan. The solution was to delete ~/.xsane (it seems that the old settings file was the source of the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in a [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xsane/+bug/478761).  What seems to be happening is that `xsane` is getting mixed up between the webcam and the scanner.

Here is the workaround from Launchpad:

- Open `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` file.

Add the following two lines to the end of the device list, before the line `# The
following rule will disable ...`

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

- Unplug webcam from the USB and reboot
- Install (or reinstall) the 3 Brother packages for the device

  - mfc210clpr-1.0.2-1.i386.deb
  - cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb
  - brscan2-0.2.4-0.i386.deb
- Plug the webcam back in
- Reboot
- `xsane` then offers a choice of whether to scan from webcam or scanner. Choose scanner.  It will then work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your account member of the scanner group? I had the same error message with brscan3 (for a DPC-185C), adding my account to the scanner group did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I spent about an hour trying to solve this one. My system was working then produced the error in question. I knew it was unlikely to be one of the complicated solutions since it was working. It was so simple - the preview scan area was accidentally set to a very small number of pixels. Once this was reset - it worked fine!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.